# Can't receive the json response being passed from rest api in html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

Rest Api in is able to create json but my ajax is not able to receive the json content being passed from rest api.

```
function loadJsonData(){

    var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8085/ParsingJson/rest/service/resources/getjsondata/'+dropDownValue,
        type:'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = data;
        load();
        },
        error:function(){alert('error');}
    }
);
}
```

Rest api response code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getjsondata/{dropDownValue}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<DummyPojo>  getJsonData(@PathVariable String dropDownValue) throws ApplicationException, ParseException{

    System.out.println("In For Json Data:: " + dropDownValue);

    DummyPojo dp = new DummyPojo();
    dp.setAge("14");
    dp.setName("Cap");
    return new ResponseEntity<DummyPojo>(dp,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I want the JSON data in my html file.

Comment: Change `alert(data);` to `console.log(data);` and then look in the browser console.  Alert will most likely display `[Object object]` which is no help, but the console will display objects as object (not strings).  Run the page and let us know what response you get.

Comment: console.log(data); is also blank.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two possibility

- dropDownValue is null OR
- mySavedModel is not loaded yet

Please make sure that your page DOM is loaded before calling the **loadJsonData**

Comment: DropDownValue is being passed succesfully and JSON is getting created at the client side only prob is it is not getting passed from rest api to ajax.

Comment: Can you please test with returning just DummyPojo instead of ResponseEntity<DummyPojo> i.e. return dp;

Comment: after changing the return type to DummyPojo, ajax call is giving error alert.